# HTML parsing using DOM-Java

Tags: java, html, dom

I want to parse a HTML file using Java and i have used `DocumentBuilder` class for it. My HTML contains a `<img src="xyz">` tag, without a closing `</img>` tag,which is allowed in browser.But when i give it to `DocumentBuilder` for parsing it gives me this error

> The element type "img" must be terminated by the matching end-tag
>   `</img>`.

Java :

```
DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document document = docBuilder.parse(is);
```

What should i do to get rid of this error?

Comment: `The element type "img" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</img>".` You probably need valid html to parse it. All tags must have ending part, or at least be defined as `<img src="xyz" />`

Comment: HTML *isn't* XML and isn't subject to the same validation

Comment: @Jakuje but <img> without a closing tag is a valid html.For ex : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_image_test

Comment: libxml2 doesn't have this problem. It shuts up about the Official Rules and just parses that HTML, subject to varying levels of validation...

Answer (score 5):

`DocumentBuilder` is part of Java's XML parsing framework. An XML parser will not correctly parse HTML: the languages look similar, but XML has stricter requirements. (You've already seen one of the differences: in XML, all tags should have a matching end tag, while in HTML some tags do and some don't.)

Try a HTML parser instead. I've heard good things about `jsoup` (http://jsoup.org/).

Comment: Thanks i will try that.But are there any disadvantages of using jsoup?

Comment: I need to run XPath queries on the HTML. Just like (ahem) Gnome's libxml2 can do...

Answer (score 0):

You can also use [TagSoup](http://home.ccil.org/~cowan/tagsoup/) to parse HTML as if it were XML, though that will give you SAX rather than DOM.