# Java HTML Stripping

Tags: java

```
//Method for Strip HTML
public static String stripHtml(String inStr) {
  boolean inTag = false;
  char c;
  StringBuffer outStr = new StringBuffer();
  int len = inStr.length();
  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    c = inStr.charAt(i);
    if (c == '<') {
      inTag = true;
    }
    if (!inTag) {
      outStr.append(c);
    }
    if (c == '>') {
      inTag = false;
    }
  }
  //Print to show that the this method is removing the necessary characters
  System.out.println(outStr);
  return outStr.toString();
}
```

So I need all outputs containing <> to be cleansed and everything in between it, and it should still print out the remaining characters. for instance

```
input:app<html>le
expected:apple
```

however it should also remove if it finds just "<" or ">" but my method isn't doing so.

```
input:app<le
output:app<le
expected:apple
```

please let me know what to fix.

Comment: https://jsoup.org/

Comment: You have several choices.  One alternative is to use an HTML parser like [jsoup](https://jsoup.org/cookbook/).  Another is to use Java [String.replaceAll()](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-replaceall), with a [regex](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_regex.asp).  You should also look hard at whether or not you actually want "remove if it finds just "<" or ">"...  Would this be "malformed HTML"... or would you risk corrupting a valid expression like "1 < 2"?

Answer (score 2):

Try parsing HTML using an HTML parser like JSoup or TagSoup.
Once you have the DOM, on the root element just call `getTextContent()`.

From the [API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getTextContent--) (never versions of Java act the same):
*This attribute returns the text content of this node and its descendants. [...] no serialization is performed, the returned string does not contain any markup.*

See also

- [Reading HTML file to DOM tree using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457684/reading-html-file-to-dom-tree-using-java)
- [HTML parsing using DOM-Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31938166/html-parsing-using-dom-java)

Answer (score 0):

It works fine with Jsoup, as someone said.

```
String input = "app<html>le";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input);
System.out.println(doc.wholeText());  // or doc.text()
```

output:

```
apple
```

But the example you gave is not a proper XML document and cannot be processed using XML parsers.

You can also modify your program slightly.

```
public static String stripHtml(String inStr) {
    boolean inTag = false;
    StringBuffer outStr = new StringBuffer();
    int len = inStr.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        char c = inStr.charAt(i);
        if (c == '<') {
            inTag = true;
        } else if (c == '>') {
            inTag = false;
        } else if (!inTag) {
            outStr.append(c);
        }
    }
    return outStr.toString();
}
```

and

```
String input = "app<html>le";
System.out.println(stripHtml(input));
```

output:

```
apple
```

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement is to remove a paired `<...>` and not handle sole `<`s.

This means that your code may only drop the in-tag characters when encountering `>`-

Your code could also use `ìnt i2 = inStr.indexOf('>', i+1);` to find a closing `>` at `<`.

However simpler is to use a regular expression replace:

```
public static String stripHtml(String s) {
    return s.replaceAll("<[^>]*>", "");
}
```

This searches all:

1. `<`
2. a not-`>`, 0 or more times (`*`)
3. `>`